# Profile picture not showing in Sharepoint List, Microsoft List on PC, but shows it on Microsoft List on mobile phone

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have made a Sharepoint List that contains a column Person which shows the profile picture and name of the person. In the column Person i have used JSON-code. The code is correct.

**ONLY** the Sharepoint list and the Microsoft list on the PC does not show the profile picture of everybody. Some will be showed others not. While when i installed the Microsoft List app on my mobile phone and I open my list the profile picture of everybode will be showed.

Sharepoint List and Microsoft List on my PC:

[image]

Microsoft List on my mobile phone:

[image]

What could be the problem? How can i solve this?

Greetings,

Peter Kiers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common issue / bug that I saw across many tenants over the past few years.

Usually it helps to just wait for a while before the images start showing up properly. I have noticed that you can force the image to show up if you navigate to the user's personal profile.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the profile pictures of the issued user are listed under this location (User Photos Document Library):

```
https://<tenant>-my.sharepoint.com/User Photos/Profile Pictures
```

They are probably stored but as the default icons instead of uploaded photos. You can replace those pictures with the photos and see if it displays correctly.

References: [Office 365 Profile Picture Not Displayed Inside SharePoint Online Webparts.](https://www.mrsharepoint.guru/office-365-profile-picture-not-displayed/)